# How to write nested regex to find words below some string?

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

> I am converting one pdf to text with xpdf and then find some words
>   with help of regex and preg_match_all.
>
> I am seperating my words with colon in pdftotext.

Below is my pdftotext output:

```
                                 In respect of Shareholders

Name:                                    xyx

Residential address:                     dublin

No of Shares:                            2

Name:                                    abc

Residential address:                     canada

No of Shares:                            2
```

So i write one regex that will show me words after colon in text().

```
$regex = '/(?<=: ).+/';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

But Now i want regex  that will display all data after `In respect of Shareholders`.

So, i write $regex = '/(?<=In respect of Shareholders).*?(?=\s)';

But it shows me only :

```
Name:                                    xyx
```

I want first to find all data after `In respect of shareholders` and then another regex to find words after colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|In respect of Shareholders)\s*[^:\r\n]+:\h*\K.*~', $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n9bwqY/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|In respect of Shareholders)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `In respect of Shareholders` text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[^:\n\r]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`, CR and LF
- `:` - a colon
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `.*` - the rest of the line (0 or more chars other than line break chars).

Comment: hey bro i just found that this code is not working if my characters are inside brackets. suppose `(In respect of Shareholders)` . in this case its not working. can you please provide me with best possible answer.

Comment: @amitsutar Replace  `In respect of Shareholders` with `\(In respect of Shareholders\)`

Comment: i am trying this code with `http://www.writephponline.com/` its not working. I am just replacing my regex `if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\(In respect of Shareholders\))\s*[^:\r\n]+:\h*\K.*~', $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}`

Comment: @amitsutar See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Ibc7h). Please share yours if it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `(?<=: ).+` you will match any character 1+ times after a colon and a space. To capture all that follows the spaces or tabs in a group, you could use `(?<=: )[\t ](.+)`

Another way to match the texts using a capturing group could be:

`^.*?:[ \t]+(\w+)`

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `.*?:` Match any character non greedy followed by a `:`
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ times a space or a tab
- `(\w+)` Capture in a group 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jCASDz/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/43vjD)

Or use `\K` to forget what was matched if that is supported:

`^.*?:\h*\K\w+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELQl5e/1/)